# In cypress, can you do a cy.setInputText by passing in a component rather than a string?

Tags: cypress

I have a Cypress test in which I would like to pass in a component to cy.setInputText rathern than a string.

Basically, instead of doing this:

```
cy.setInputText('[data-cy="myTextField"]', 'some text');
```

I would like to do something this:

```
cy.setInputText($row.find('td:nth-child(2)'), 'some text');
```

But of course that doesn't work since cy.setInputText is expecting a string rather than a component.

Any suggestions?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this.  You just have to grab whatever you need with a cy.get and then do a .type like so...

```
cy.get('p-table#myTable tbody').find('tr:nth-child(1)').find('td:nth-child(2)').type('1234');
```